# How to add a summary row for dynamically generated columns?

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions, pivot-table

I have two tables, which are pretty like those [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619474/turning-table-rows-into-columns-in-mysql).

But I have not only to create a pivot table whith dynamically generated columns, but also to get a summary row with a total for each column. That is, given [this  tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619474/turning-table-rows-into-columns-in-mysql), my pivot table should appear like this:

```
╔══════════════╦══════════════╦══════════════╗
║ STUDENT_NAME ║ ITEM_1_SCORE ║ ITEM_2_SCORE ║
╠══════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╣
║ dan          ║         55   ║         44   ║
║ david        ║         66   ║         45   ║
║ jon          ║         37   ║         45   ║
╠══════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╣
║SUM           ║       158    ║        134   ║
```

I tried this solution (which works great in itself):

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN item_id = ''',
               item_id,
               ''' THEN Score END) AS ',
               CONCAT('`Item_', item_id, '_Score`')
               )) INTO @sql
FROM scores;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT   a.Name AS Student_Name, ', @sql, ' 
                    FROM    student_info a
                            LEFT JOIN scores b
                                ON a.id = b.student_ID
                    GROUP   BY a.Name');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

but addition of `WITH ROLLUP` gives maximum value, not the sum. I also tried to use

`(SELECT ...) UNION (SELECT "SUM" as Student_Name, SUM(Score) as Item1 ...etc`,

but it worked only with predefined fixed numbers of columns.

Thanks for any assistance.